# Why do I get a segmentation fault when calling getc?

Tags: c, stdio

```
// Program to remove the comments and the spaces from the given input file
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    FILE *input_file, *output_file;

    input_file = fopen("input", "r");
    output_file = fopen("output", "w");

    char c1,c2;

    c1 = getc(input_file); // taking the first character of the file
    c2 = getc(input_file); // Shows segmentation fault here

    while(c1 != EOF)
    {
        if(c1 == '/' && c2 == '/') // if it is a single line comment
        {
            c1 = getc(input_file);


            while(c1 != '\n') // keep scanning until \n character is found
            {
                c1 = c2;
                c2 = getc(input_file);
            }
        }

       else if(c1 == '/' && c2 == '*') // for multi line comment
        {
            while(c1 != '*' && c2 != '/')
            {
                c1 = c2;
                c2 = getc(input_file);
            }

            c1 = getc(input_file);
            c2 = getc(input_file);
        }

        else if(c1 == '\n' && c2 == '\n') // to remove extra newline characters
            while(c1 == '\n')
                c1 = getc(input_file);

        else if(c1 == ' ' && c2 == ' ') // to remove extra whitespaces
            while(c1 == ' ')
                c1 = getc(input_file);
        else
            putc(c1, output_file);

        c1 = c2;
        c2 = getc(input_file);
    }
}
```

I am trying to remove the comments and whitespaces from an input file. But, when I run this code using GCC compiler in code blocks in Windows 8, it stops working.

While compiling this program no error is shown but executing it it stops working.

I tried running the debugger and it shows segmentation fault in the line marked in the code.

EDIT:

I checked again and found out that the input_file is a NULL pointer. 
But, I have a file in the project folder named input(.txt) file. 
Why is it a NULL pointer then?

Comment: Well, you don't check if either file is actually opened.  That would be a good start.

Comment: Check the result of `fopen` (you should be doing this anyway).  You should also check that the result of the first `getc` is not `EOF`.

Comment: `getc` returns `int`, not `char`. Using `char c1, c2` means the check for `EOF` is not correct.

Comment: Why are you mixing C and C++?

Comment: You blame him for not coding properly (checks) but at the same time no one cares about bad documentation. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getc/ , e.g. does not state what is supposed to happen if you getc(f) for a file which is at EOF already. It neither says "undefined behavior" nor anything else. I am inclined to think that his development environment is not working properly as I think to remember that reading at EOF is just supposed to result in more EOF but not in a segmentation fault.

Comment: Per your edit, you need to supply the *entire* file name for the `fopen` call to work correctly.

Comment: @user2225104 what are you talking about? It states explicitly: `"If the stream is at the end-of-file when called, the function returns EOF and sets the end-of-file indicator for the stream "`

Comment: What *exactly* is the name of the file in the project folder? You say it's "input(.txt)". Are there really parentheses in the file name? You're trying to open a file named `"input"`, which is not the same as `"input.txt"`.

Comment: @aruisdante That statement is still kind of fuzzy. It can be interpreted as "in all states (eof, error) it behaves as described". But it need not be. Someone could argue that this is only what happens the first time and that subsequent calls result in whatever behavior.  At least to my taste, I would prefer more formal ways of documentation.

Comment: @user2225104 I'm confused as how "If the stream is at end-of-file when called" is at all ambiguous. The only thing that could be argued slightly is that it doesn't state what happens if you try and read from a stream in an error condition, only on what happens if the read causes the error condition. But it's definitely pretty clear on what happens with a stream at EOF.

Comment: @user2225104: Only someone determined to misinterpret the text could do so.  It says that "if the stream is at end-of-file when called, the function returns EOF".  It is at EOF each time it is called after EOF is detected, so EOF is returned each time.  It is much more likely that the OP mis-detected which line causes the segmentation fault, or possibly the compiler was confused by the macro expansion of `getc()` — which may be a macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input` and `input(.txt)` are different filenames (as is `input.txt` if that's what you meant).  You will need to specify the exact name of the file.

Of course, you should check `input_file` and `output_file` are not `NULL` before trying to do any read/write operatons on them. If they are null then you may get a clue as to what went wrong by checking out `errno`, perhaps via the `perror` function, e.g.:

```
input_file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
if ( !input_file )
{
    perror("Failed to open input file: ");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Other problems:

- `c1` and `c2` must have type `int`. This is because `EOF` is out-of-band of any valid character value (as returned by `fgetc`).
- In the `while(c1 != '\n')`, and the next `while` loop, you also need to check `c1 != EOF` otherwise this will be an infinite loop if end-of-file occurs before a `\n`.